# how to make rpoption in flexigrid input box rather than a drop down?

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

```
    $("#flex1").flexigrid(
    {
        url: 'http://xyz.com', 
        dataType: 'json',

        buttons : [
            {name:'Delete', 
            bclass: 'delete', 
            onpress: deleteitem},
            {name:'Add New Manufacturer', 
            bclass: 'add', 
            onpress: additem}
        ],
        searchitems : [
            {display: 'Manufacturer', 
             name : 'manufacturer_name', 
             isdefault:true},
            ],
        sortname: "mid",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        title: '<?=$this->pageHeading?>',
        useRp: true,
        rpOptions: ['20','30','40','10'],
        rp: $("#rp").val(),
        showTableToggleBtn: true,
        singleSelect : true,
        height: 265,
        width: 1000,
        autowidth:false
    }
    );
```

In Flexigrid rp options are usually drop down which we define just as above.. how can we change it to a input box??

Comment: Hi, could you add more tags.. It is not clear what is been asked here.

Comment: for displaying number of records at a time we use rp options like here i used 20, 30 ,40.. so we can select 20, 30 or 40 but i want textbox instead of drop down.. how can i do that??